# How to downsample/aggregate R rasters with custom function to produce multiple output rasters?

Tags: r, aggregate, raster, r-raster, downsampling

I have a rather complex function that I'm using to compute aggregates of raster-cells (downsampling). In this function I'm distuingishing between multiple cases, where the case determines which summary function is used. As a simplified example (let's assume, `42`, `77` and `123` are dynamically computed values dependent on vec):

```
my_fun <- function(vec, na.rm=TRUE, VERBOSE = FALSE){
  if(max(vec) > 1){
    print("case 1")
    return(42)
  } else if(max(vec) > 2){
    print("case 2")
    return(123)
  } else {
    print("case 3")
    return(77)
  }
}

vhm_2 = raster::aggregate(vhm, 20, fun=my_fun, expand=TRUE, na.rm=FALSE)
```

This would result in a raster with values `42`, `77` and `123`. **In addition to this I'd like a second raster, indicating which case was used, i.e. a raster saying containing numbers 1-3 for each cell.**

Of course I can run it twice, with a second function that just returns the case number (instead of the "computation"), however I'm processing large rasters and the computations (for determining the case, as well as the actual value) are expensive in the first place, so I'd love to avoid this.

The [doc](http://%20https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-11/topics/aggregate) explicitly says that `fun` needs to return a single number, so my hopes that I could simply return both case number AND computed value were shattered. Is there another (computationally efficient) way to aggregate rasters with custom functions where I could get two rasters as output?
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-11/topics/aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now do this with `terra 1.5.15` (currently the development version. You can install it with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.5.15
r <- rast()
set.seed(1)
values(r) <- sample(100, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
a <- aggregate(r, 10, range)
a
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 18, 36, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : memory 
#names       : lyr.1, lyr.2 
#min values  :     1,    95 
#max values  :     7,   100
```

Or with a custom function

```
a_fun <- function(v){
  m <- max(v)
  if(m < 80){
    c(1,42)
  } else if(m < 95){
    c(2,123)
  } else {
    c(3, 77)
  }
}

a <- aggregate(r, 5, fun=a_fun)
a
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 36, 72, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 5, 5  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : memory 
#names       : lyr.1, lyr.2 
#min values  :     1,    42 
#max values  :     3,   123
```

But in this case you could also opt to do:

```
a_fun <- function(v){
  m <- max(v)
  if(m < 80){
    1
  } else if(m < 95){
    2
  } else {
    3
  }
}

a <- aggregate(r, 5, fun=a_fun)
b <- classify(a, matrix(c(1,42, 2,123, 3, 77), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
```